# How to get this green syntax highlight for html output?

Tags: html, css, rstudio, knitr

I have came across this `html` produced by `Knit to HTML` from Rstudio.

[image]

I've tried all options in Rstudio but can not get the same result.

[image]

Could you please explain how to get this theme? Below is my setup:

```
output:
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
    highlight: tango
    theme: journal
    number_subsections: no
  word_document:
    toc: yes
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    number_sections: yes
always_allow_html: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this theme does not exist then it is surely a custom theme. Try the dark theme or follow this link for more info.
https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html

this another link for setup theme
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011846747-Using-RStudio-Themes